# Xcode not loading the main target

Tags: xcode

I'm using XCode 14.3.1.

Many times when I open a project (in this case a Workspace with pods that also has Extension Targets) the extension target will load but not the main target. I have to close and open several times until the main target actually loads and I'm able to run the project.

Is there a way to fix this?